# Convergence of the perimeter of level sets

Tags: limits-and-convergence, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure, limsup-and-liminf

I have already posted this question on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748367/convergence-of-the-perimeter-of-level-sets). Suppose you have a sequence of $C^1$ functions $\{\phi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that converges in $C^{1}_{\mathrm{loc}}$ to a function $\phi$, as $n \to +\infty$. By $C^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ convergence I mean that
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sup_{x\in K} |\phi_n(x)-\phi(x)|+|\nabla \phi_n(x)- \nabla \phi(x)|=0
$$
for every $K\Subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose also that all functions are coercive ($\{\phi(x) \leq M\}$ and $\{\phi_n(x) \leq M\}$ are compact for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}$). Let $a<b$ be in the image of $\phi$ and $\phi_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. **Can one show that
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi_n(x) \leq t\} )= \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi(x)\leq t\})
$$
for almost every $t \in [a,b]$?**

The liminf identity
$$
\liminf_{n \to +\infty} \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi_n(x) \leq t\} )= \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi(x)\leq t\})
$$
follows by Fatou's lemma and coarea formula. Indeed, the '$\geq$' inequality is a consequence of the lower semicontinuity of the perimeter under $L^1$ convergence of sublevel sets. On the other hand,
\begin{align}
0 &\leq \int_a^b \liminf_{n\to +\infty}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi_n(x) \leq t\}) - \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi(x)\leq t\}) \,\mathrm{d}t\\&\leq \liminf_{n\to+\infty}\int_a^b \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi_n(x) \leq t\} )- \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial \{\phi(x)\leq t\}) \,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\int\limits_{\{a\leq \phi_n\leq b\}} |\nabla \phi_n(x)| \,\mathrm{d} x - \int\limits_{\{a\leq \phi\leq b\}} |\nabla \phi(x)| \,\mathrm{d} x =0,
\end{align}
where the last identity is a consequence of the $C^1$ convergence. Can this liminf be improved to a full limit?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is automatic from what you already proved: Pick a sequence $n_j$ along which the LHS converges to the $\limsup$, and apply your result to this sequence.

Comment: @ChristianRemling the subsequence $n_j$ you pick (along which the LHS converges to $\limsup$) depends on $t$, doesn't it? Maybe I am missing something obvious, but how can you use Fatou in this case? Could you explain your idea?